# How to configure docker swarm using jenkins?

Tags: shell, jenkins, docker-swarm

I have got an assignment. The assignment is "Write a shell script to install and configure docker swarm(one master/leader and one node) and automate the process using Jenkins." I am new to this technology and finding it difficult to proceed. Can anyone help me in explaining step-by-step process of how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

@Rajnish Kumar Singh, Have you tried to check resources online? I understand you are very new to this technology, but googling some key words like

- what is docker swarm
- what is jenkins , etc would definitely helps

Having said that, Basically you need to do below set of steps to complete your assignment

Pre-requisites

- 2 or more - Ubuntu 20.04 Server
  (You can use any linux distros like ubuntu, Redhat etc, But make sure your install and execute commands change accordingly.
  Here we need two nodes mainly to configure the master and worker node cluster)

Eg :

- manager  ---   132.92.41.4
- worker  ---  132.92.41.5

You can create these nodes in any of public cloud providers like AWS EC2 instances or GCP VMs etc

Next, You need to do below set of steps

1. Configure Hosts
2. Install Docker-ce
3. Docker Swarm Initialization

You can refer this article for more info https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/ubuntu-docker-swarm-cluster/

This completes first part of your assignment.

Next, You can create one small shell script and include all those install and configuration commands in that script. Basically shell script is collection of set of linux commands. Instead of running each commands separately , you will run script alone and all set up will be done for you.

1. You can create small script using touch command

```
touch docker-swarm-install.sh
```

2. Specify proper privileges to script to make it executable

```
chmod +x docker-swarm-install.sh
```

3. Next include all your install + configure commands, which you have used earlier to do docker swarm set up in scripts (You can refer above shared link)

Now, when your script is ready, you can configure this script in jenkins job and whenever jenkins job is run, script will get execute and docker swarm cluster will be created

1. You need a jenkins server. Jenkins is open source software, you can install it in any of public cloud instance (Aws EC2)
   Reference : https://devopsarticle.com/how-to-install-jenkins-on-aws-ec2-ubuntu-20-04/
2. Next once installation is completed. You need to configure job in jenkins
   Reference : https://www.toolsqa.com/jenkins/jenkins-build-jobs/
3. Add your 'docker-swarm-install.sh' as build step in created job
   Reference : https://faun.pub/jenkins-jobs-hands-on-for-the-different-use-cases-devops-b153efb483c7

If all set up is successful and now when you run your jenkins job, your docker swarm cluster must be get created.